# ggplot2 barplot multiple overlapping confidence interval

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, errorbar

I am trying to make a barplot, and came across an issue with having multiple overlapping error bar when using geom_errorbar in R.

```
## Use ggplot for bargraph
dat3$EDU_B <- as.factor(dplyr::recode(dat3$EDU_B,
                                      "-0.5" = "No BA",
                                      "0.5" = "BA or Higher"))

dat3$DISC_LB <- as.factor(dplyr::recode(dat3$DISC_LB,
                                      "-0.5" = "None",
                                      "0.5" = "Once or More"))

m_graph <- glm(Vac~AGE+SEX+R_Ethgp+hea+SUPP+EDU_B*DISC_LB, data=dat3, family="binomial"(link="logit"))

d_graph<- expand.grid(EDU_B=c("No BA", "BA or Higher"), 
                      DISC_LB = c("None", "Once or More"),
                      AGE = mean(dat3$AGE, na.rm=TRUE), SEX = as.factor(c("1", "2")), R_Ethgp = as.factor(c("1", "2", "3")),
                      hea=mean(dat3$hea, na.rm=TRUE),
                      SUPP=mean(dat3$SUPP, na.rm=TRUE))


d_graph <- ggplotPredict(m_graph, d_graph)

colours <- setNames(c("gray", "black"), 
                    c("None", "Once or More"))

ggplot(d_graph, aes(x = EDU_B, y = Predicted, fill = DISC_LB)) +
geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(width = .5), width = .5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = CILo, ymax = CIHi), position = position_dodge(width = .5), width = .25) +
  labs(x = 'EDU_B',
       y = 'Vac',
       fill = "DISC_LB") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color="black"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color="black"), panel.border = element_blank(), 
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colours)
```

This code shows the below barplot:

[image: barplot outcome]

dput(d_graph) outcome is as below:

```
structure(list(Predicted = c(0.741733907298891, 0.893756128438394, 
0.753034460658107, 0.844328967902538, 0.690516055803563, 0.867292483919938, 
0.703160805745206, 0.808195916427015, 0.72652210305617, 0.886123699935912, 
0.738253376025301, 0.83380602202825, 0.673614979456173, 0.858060859719625, 
0.686636893380215, 0.795821126990505, 0.756261079495159, 0.900874986909593, 
0.767125555910493, 0.8542194901226, 0.706785307496624, 0.875938400246907, 
0.719035804605874, 0.819892436521564), CILo = c(0.715042531267134, 
0.879798887274131, 0.723169362160149, 0.824203005032667, 0.662243435508124, 
0.850948845952362, 0.671328969582244, 0.78632684692288, 0.683373949583467, 
0.861484206821811, 0.696028073246912, 0.801850170598328, 0.629603044714273, 
0.830165337690498, 0.64352199113624, 0.761701452826876, 0.717667779348929, 
0.881149420462295, 0.730439261597285, 0.827893111224002, 0.666379378466323, 
0.853326521810591, 0.680743413133101, 0.791428074348007), CIHi = c(0.766740741785983, 
0.906265380398855, 0.780654887628222, 0.862535118114526, 0.717431853735625, 
0.882092336078731, 0.733135236691968, 0.828315421381777, 0.765805349072594, 
0.906854159078416, 0.776496600435928, 0.861498477136563, 0.714766483640827, 
0.882025639872601, 0.726751381800773, 0.826170411398003, 0.791114377817812, 
0.917632740850175, 0.800184797380489, 0.877116574262168, 0.744176233516029, 
0.895491256713494, 0.754392395912261, 0.84523184833694), SE = c(0.0266913760317568, 
0.0139572411642636, 0.0298650984979582, 0.0201259628698712, 0.0282726202954383, 
0.0163436379675761, 0.0318318361629623, 0.021869069504135, 0.0431481534727024, 
0.0246394931141003, 0.0422253027783889, 0.0319558514299214, 0.0440119347418992, 
0.0278955220291265, 0.0431149022439746, 0.0341196741636288, 0.0385933001462304, 
0.0197255664472985, 0.0366862943132076, 0.0263263788985977, 0.0404059290303008, 
0.0226118784363158, 0.0382923914727727, 0.0284643621735564), 
    EDU_B = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("No BA", 
    "BA or Higher"), class = "factor"), DISC_LB = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("None", "Once or More"
    ), class = "factor"), AGE = c(1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 
    1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 
    1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 
    1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 
    1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 
    1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 
    1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 
    1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 1.53750183316577e-14, 
    1.53750183316577e-14), SEX = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    R_Ethgp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
    ), levels = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), hea = c(-2.95655099318715e-15, 
    -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, 
    -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, 
    -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, 
    -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, 
    -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, 
    -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, 
    -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15, 
    -2.95655099318715e-15, -2.95655099318715e-15), SUPP = c(3.04891640608375e-16, 
    3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 
    3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 
    3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 
    3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 
    3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 
    3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 
    3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16, 
    3.04891640608375e-16, 3.04891640608375e-16)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"
))
```

How can I fix the problem?

Thank you!

I want to have only one error bar for each bar, but the code that I run shows multiple overlapping bar.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The most likely reason is that you have multiple rows of data for each combo of EDU_B and DISC_LB. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data best shared via `dput`, e.g. run `dput(d_graph)` and copy the output into your post.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! I just uploaded the data using dput.

Answer (score 1):

As I already guessed in my comment the issue is that you multiple rows for each combo of `EDU_B` and `DISC_LB` in your dataset, i.e. 6 rows in total reflecting the combos of `SEX` and `R_Ethgp`.

One option to fix that would be to use facetting as I do below or filter your dataset or ...

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d_graph, aes(x = EDU_B, y = Predicted, fill = DISC_LB)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = .5), width = .5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = CILo, ymax = CIHi),
    position = position_dodge(width = .5), width = .25
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "EDU_B",
    y = "Vac",
    fill = "DISC_LB"
  ) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
    axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black"),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours) +
  facet_grid(SEX ~ R_Ethgp, labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

**EDIT** And if you just want to show the effect for two variables holding all other covariates fixed at some average value, then you you have to set up your data accordingly.

Wasn't able to find a function `ggplotPredict` when googling. Instead I use `ggeffects::ggpredict` in the code below and some random fake example data:

```r
library(ggeffects)
library(ggplot2)

### Example data
set.seed(1)

dat3 <- expand.grid(
  EDU_B = c("No BA", "BA or Higher"),
  DISC_LB = c("None", "Once or More"),
  AGE = c(1:10),
  SEX = factor(c("1", "2")),
  R_Ethgp = factor(c("1", "2", "3")),
  hea = c(1:10),
  SUPP = c(1:10),
  id = 1:10
)
dat3$Vac <- sample(0:1, nrow(dat3), replace = TRUE)
###

m_graph <- glm(Vac ~ AGE + SEX + R_Ethgp + hea + SUPP + EDU_B * DISC_LB,
  data = dat3, family = "binomial"(link = "logit")
)

d_graph <- ggeffects::ggpredict(m_graph, terms = c("EDU_B", "DISC_LB"))

colours <- setNames(
  c("gray", "black"),
  c("None", "Once or More")
)

ggplot(d_graph, aes(x = x, y = predicted, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = .5), width = .5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high),
    position = position_dodge(width = .5), width = .25
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "EDU_B",
    y = "Vac",
    fill = "DISC_LB"
  ) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
    axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black"), panel.border = element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed suggestions! However, I wanted to treat Sex and R_Ethgp as covariates. Is there a way to make a barplot while controlling for them?

Comment: Not really suggestions. Just meant to make the issue with the multiple rows visible. See my edit on one approach to achieve your desired result.